# The repository does not have a Release file in newly added repo

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I'm trying to build docker container. The core OS inside is Ubuntu.

```
FROM ubuntu@sha256:703218c0465075f4425e58fac086e09e1de5c340b12976ab9eb8ad26615c3715
```

I want to install some packages from apt.armbian.com . For that I put this into the dockerfile:

```
RUN echo "deb http://apt.armbian.com buster main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/apt.armbian.com.list \
&& wget -O -  apt.armbian.com/armbian.key | apt-key add - \
&& apt-get update && apt-get upgrade \
&& apt install media-buster-legacy-rk3399 gl4es
```

But it gives me:

```
Err:6 http://armbian.hosthatch.com/apt buster-desktop Release
404  Not Found [IP: 31.220.4.23 80]
Reading package lists...
E: The repository 'http://apt.armbian.com buster-desktop Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Where could be my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `apt.armbian.com` is a redirector for apt repository, try opening `apt.armbian.com` in your browser then use the mirror, e,g:

```
wget  -O - https://stpete-mirror.armbian.com/apt/armbian.key |apt-key add -
```

see `curl -v apt.armbian.com`

sample output:

```
<p>You should be redirected automatically to target URL: <a href="http://armbian.16z.eu/apt/">http://armbian.16z.eu/apt/</a>
```

In the above example, you can use the `http://armbian.16z.eu/apt/`

To install `media-buster-legacy-rk3399`, add this to your file:

```
wget https://armbian.hosthatch.com/apt/pool/buster-desktop/m/media-buster-legacy-rk3399/media-buster-legacy-rk3399_20.11.7_arm64.deb
apt install ./media-buster-legacy-rk3399_20.11.7_arm64.deb
```

Comment: Yes, that helped. I have "Unable to locate package media-buster-legacy-rk3399" now, but it's another thing. Thanks.

Comment: @Dmitry I am not experienced with Armbian but I have edited the answer to install the desired package.